# Bokeh: gridplot to components flexible layout option

Tags: python, bokeh

using gridplot(), I can easily layout different plots on a grid, using components() the combined html for all plots is returned to my view as a single variable, div_combined.

I would like to include some descriptions above each plot laid out in my gridplot html, but don't know how to modify the div_combined in my view. would I be better off to not use gridplot, and just return each plot html separately, then create the additional grid html?

```
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p1,p2,p3,p4 = figure()
grid = gridplot([[p1, p2], [p3, p4]], plot_width=563, plot_height=325)
script_combined, div_combined = components(grid)

msg = 'Dashboard'
return render_template('grid_view_with_desc.html', msg=msg, script_combined=script_combined, div_combined=div_combined)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
p1,p2,p3,p4 = figure()
```

Try this:

```
p1 = figure(plot_width=563, plot_height=325, title='P1 title goes here')
p2 = figure(plot_width=563, plot_height=325, title='P2 title goes here')
p3 = figure(plot_width=563, plot_height=325, title='P3 title goes here')
p4 = figure(plot_width=563, plot_height=325, title='P4 title goes here')
```

Should work...?

Comment: thanks, I need like a whole paragraph of description, I guess I have to find another way